# setup git push/pull to localhost without public IP address in a ssh session

Tags: git, ssh

I have such a problem to deal with:

I use a git in my localhost while I do my work through ssh to a pc with a public IP address.
But the problem is, I am residing behind a NAT router which means I do not have any public IP address.
So I just send the whole git repo to the remote machine. But I want to setup git pull (pull/push updates from/to local machine ) in the remote machine, is there any possible way to do it?

Comment: you should set up dyndns or establish a tunnel  from the natted box to a site that can be reached from the other side

Answer (score 0):

If localhost doesn't have a public IP address, you won't be able to connect to it from the remote machine. You must initiate all commands (e.g. `git push`, `git pull`, `git fetch` from localhost, otherwise it won't work.